# Make some filters on an array then unfilter with an "All" filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filtering, state

I am building the classic "todo" app in React.
I want to implement the funcionality to filter todos based on status: completed, active, and all.

I usually copy my original state, and then apply changes to the copy.

The problem is that I lose my original TODOs when I use filter on the array, so when I use the 'All' button I can't retrieve my data before the filtering.

This is my state:

```
  state = {
    todos: [
      { id: 432402, title: "Make some music", isDone: false },
      { id: 421402, title: "Conquer the world", isDone: false },
      { id: 427740, title: "Go to the mall", isDone: true },
      { id: 471402, title: "Do some homework", isDone: false }
    ]
  };
```

This is one of the function I use to filter the state based on completed status

```
  filterCompletedTasks = () => {
    const todos = [...this.state.todos];
    const filtered = todos.filter(todo => {
      return todo.isDone;
  });
```

I don't use redux or Immutable.js at the moment, so any help with using simple React would be extremely useful.

Comment: are you modifying the state after filtering, how are you using filterCompletedTasks. Need more code to be able to help

Comment: yep. I use 

this.setState({ todos: filtered });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key idea is to keep all the items non-modified in your state. 
I reproduced your example. Take a look at it. I added `showDone` variable to the state to add basic filtering flexibility to your app. When `showDone` equals `true` , I apply `filter` method on `state.todos` and assign the result to `todosList` variable that is responsible of displaying the result.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  
  state = {
    showDone: false,
    todos: [
      { id: 432402, title: "Make some music", isDone: false },
      { id: 421402, title: "Conquer the world", isDone: false },
      { id: 427740, title: "Go to the mall", isDone: true },
      { id: 471402, title: "Do some homework", isDone: false },
    ],
  }
  
  toggleFilter = () => this.setState({ showDone: !this.state.showDone })
  
  render() {
    let todosList = this.state.todos;
    
    if (this.state.showDone) {
      todosList = todosList.filter((todo) => todo.isDone);
    }
 
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>ToDo List</h4>
        <button onClick={this.toggleFilter}>Toggle show done</button>
         {todosList.map((todo, i) => (
          <div key={todo.id}>
            {todo.title}
            {todo.isDone && <span>[DONE]</span>}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="react">
```

Comment: I think `this.setState((oldState) => { return { showDone: !oldState.showDone}; });` is a better way to achieve this.

Comment: @inaumov17: Thanks! Your solution is exactly what I wanted to know. To recap: instead of filtering the original array then setting the state equal to the filtered one, I just render a new filtered list based on a conditional statement.

Comment: @FrancescoDiBlasi you got it.